# Where are global settings stored?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings

sometimes after logging out and in again, my settings in Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories are lost.

To investigate the problem I tried to find the file where Visual Studio (2008 Team) stores those settings on disk. (Or is it in the registry?) Can anybody point me to where it is?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings

Comment: hmm, if I replace "C:\Users\username\Documents" with my My-Documents-Folder, I can see this file (had looked at it even before), but this file is not modified if I change the settings. (But I can restart VS and the settings are still ok.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem setting the Max Concurrent Builds on a CruiseControl.NET server and found that while the settings are stored in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings
The settings are also stored in the registry and the registry settings override the settings in that file
Try looking in the registry in:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\
Seems like any non-default settings are stored in the registry too